# How to update in database after select change in html select in zend

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, onchange

I have a html select dropdown list in my view

```
    <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>

    <?php if ($level == 1): ?>
         <option value="1" selected ="selected">Administrator</option>
         <option value="2" <?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>> Manager</option>
         <option value="3" <?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
     <?php elseif ($level == 2): ?>
         <option value="1" <?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
         <option value="2" selected ="selected">Manager</option>
         <option value="3" <?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
       <?php elseif ($level == 3): ?>
         <option value="1" <?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
         <option value="2" <?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>>Manager</option>
         <option value="3" selected ="selected">HR Staff</option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </select>
```

What I want is that everytime I select on my dropdown, it must update the level column in my user table in database.

I have tried using onchange event of javascript

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>


function changeLevel(level){
    var user_id = level.value; 
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/editLevel/'+user_id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                    $("#test").html(response);
                }
        });
    alert(user_id);
}

</script>
```

but it fails on calling the parent url.
this outputs http://localhost/ijm/public/%7B%7BURL()%7D%7D/editLevel/2
instead of http://localhost/ijm/public/user/editLevel/2

aside from that, how can I update my user table from that javascript function?

this is my function in userController

```
public function editLevelAction()
    {
        //return $this->$view;
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        $data = array(
                'level' => $level
        );
        $this->update('user', $data, 'id = ' .'39');

         //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user');


    }
```

what should i need to do for this to work? Thanks in advance.

Here now is the whole code.

```
<?php
$title = "Manage Users ";
$this->headtitle($title);

$identity = $this->identity()->level;
?>
<!-- these should be between the <head> tags, but make sure they are at least after the head if they can't be in the head-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?><small>User list</small></h1>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('user/add'); ?>"><i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add new user</a></li>
</ul>
<?php if (count($users)): ?>
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
   <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url('user/edit', array('id' => $user->id)); ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($user->email); ?></td>
        <td>
            <div id="test"></div>
            <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>
            <select name="level" id= "level" onchange="changeLevel(this)">
                 <option value="1" <?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" <?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>> Manager</option>
                 <option value="3" <?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url('user/delete', array('id' => $user->id)); ?>" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Delete this user"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
<h3>There are no registered users available.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeLevel(level){
        var user_id = level.value; 
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/editLevel/'+user_id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                        $("#test").html(response);
                        alert(user_id);
                    }
            });

      }
</script>
```

Comment: `"{{URL()}}/editLevel/"` in javascript **is not** valid syntax for calling a function and inserting it's return value into a string. **If** you actually have this "URL()" method defined somewhere in Javascript, try the following syntax instead: `URL()+"/editLevel/"` (just like you did with `user_id`). If you do not have that function defined anywhere, you'll need to post a more complete example for us to see. Additionally, you should probably look at using ajax instead of changing the window location.

Comment: Put the `alert(user_id);` inside the `success: function(response) { alert(user_id); }`

Comment: Also, `/editLevel/` is based on the local root, so you would need to change that url if it's not correct.

Comment: Also, usually you would send a query string like `/editLevel/?id=+user_id` or similar.

Comment: HI, just now  I add the alert inside the success function but it didnt trigger.

Comment: What is the url that needs to be hit to make your database query?

Comment: it should be like this  http://localhost/ijm/public/user/editLevel/(user_id) 
thanks Rasclatt.

Comment: What is the local root path? like is `user` your root folder? Also is it `editLevel/index.php` or what is there at that path end?

Comment: Yes i think user is the root folder. i think no, editLevel is a function on my controller.

Comment: Ok then that is where you are going wrong. You can't directly access a function via the Javascript. You need to call a page that will handle the `userController` class and it's `editLevelAction()` function in a PHP setting.

Comment: Yes, actually that is my first problem. can you help me how can i make that? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71132/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-dave).

Comment: Firstly check if you can access `yourdomain.com/editLevel/?id=2` by typing it to browser (later you need to include second parameter for user_id). Then check if your javasript works - add `alert('test')` to `chnageLevel` and `success` functions. If both things work thne use webdeveloper tools in your browser to check if there is XHR query and whats is going on with it.

Comment: i tried accessing directly thru browser and it works, unfortunately the javascript didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AJAX (here is jQuery). This is just a quick example based on yours:

**jQuery Hosted Libraries**

```
<!-- jQUERY Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Form: Select**

```
<!-- Just a div to display results if you want to -->
<div id="test"></div>

<form>
    <?php
        // Here is just a quick function to help fix your redundant 
        // select check. This could probably be done better, but you
        // don't need to echo out all 3 sets of options 3 times 
        function IsSelected($value = 1,$level = 1) {
                echo ($value == $level)? 'selected="selected"':"";
            }

        $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>

    <select name="level" id= "level" onchange="changeLevel(this)">  
         <option value="1"<?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
         <option value="2"<?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>>Manager</option>
         <option value="3"<?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**jQuery AJAX**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function changeLevel(level){
        var user_id = level.value; 
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/editLevel/'+user_id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                        $("#test").html(response);
                    }
            });

      }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Dave, a couple things to note, you have to make sure the `url:` address is correct and make sure the php on the end of  that page is functioning properly. The provided code works, guaranteed. I tested it before posting.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! but sorry it didnt work. when i try to change my selection it didnt do anything. i will update my question to post my whole code. thanks